# Is there any way to change MemoryStream speed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using this method to display in pictureBox1 animated gif i created.
The animated gif is already have it's own speed. For example 1 frame per second or i can set it to 1 frame each ms.

```
        public void pictureBoxImage(string pbImage)
        {
            Image img2 = null;
            try
            {
                using (img = Image.FromFile(pbImage))
                {
                    Image i = this.pictureBox1.Image;
                    this.pictureBox1.Image = null;

                    if (i != null)
                        i.Dispose();
                    MemoryStream m = _memSt;
                    _memSt = new MemoryStream();
                    img.Save(_memSt, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

                    if (m != null)
                        m.Dispose();
                    img2 = Image.FromStream(_memSt);

                }

                if (img2 != null)
                    pictureBox1.Image = img2;
                label2.Text = numberOfFiles.ToString();
                label6.Text = nameOfStartFile.ToString();
                label4.Text = nameOfEndFile.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Animation Error >>>   " + err);
            }
        }
```

For example pbImage contain:

C:\previewDirectory\preview.gif

My question is that if there is any way to change the MemoryStream variable speed maybe so it will display the animated gif in a different speed ? Or if the animated speed file gif on my hard disk saved as speed of 1ms for example so that is the speed and can't be changed ?

I want to in pictureBox1 using hScrollBar to change the speed of the animated gif that is displayed in the pictureBox1.

Comment: The speed of an animated GIF has nothing to do with the `MemoryStream`. It's part of the file itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing things. The animation speed is defined in the GIF file itself. I.e. a display time for each frame is defined. This has absolutely nothing to do with MemoryStreams or the speed of MemoryStreams.

If you want to change the animation speed, change it in the GIF-file by using a graphics or animation application capabale of doing it.

You can do it here: http://ezgif.com/speed